# find derivate that: $y=\frac{-\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\tan{(\frac{x}{2})})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

help me with this derivate hhe
ok, :)

Find derivate that:

$$y=\frac{-\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\tan{(\frac{x}{2})})$$

The answer is $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{sin^3x}$$
But i tried everything and am unable to arrive at the answer..

I think that

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\tan(\frac{x}{2})),$$
$$y´=\frac{1}{2}\csc(x)$$
and 
$$y=\frac{-\cos x}{\sin^2x}$$
$$y´=\frac{\sin^3x+2\cos^2x\sin x}{\sin^4x}$$

Comment: this excercises,,, book piskunov

Comment: The answer is not $csc^3 x$ as suggested.  Rather, the answer is $\frac{3+\cos^2 x}{2\sin^3 x}$.